# Animated sequence of views

Tags: android, animation

I want to implement view like this:

[image: Apple Time Machine]

Inside of this view all children has to be animated while scrolling through them.

I am going to implement it for android 2.x

My first thought was to create custom view extending FrameLayout and manage children views inside programatically, detect gestures and move to next/prev child view animating them (probably scale and transition animation)

What can you advice me, how to achive that, maybe there is an open source project that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got what I wan't, there is no simple answer on this question, but simply saying you have to all the work that android UI framework usually does: calculate position of items, add them in proper order, apply different effects (translate, scale, fade out) and draw it on canvas.

To achiev this I follod this extremely useful tutorial (thanks to author)
http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/wp/2010/05/20/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-1/

I am thinking to add my solution somewhere on github once I fix all bugs and make it completelly reusable.